# How to initialize a constant object field for a class in java

Tags: java

I wonder what is the best way to initialize a constant field of complex object type for a class , which one has the most performance?

1) Inline initialization

```
public class TopClass {
   private static final ComplexObject sdf = new ComplexObject();
            
   public TopClass (
   }
}
```

2) Initializer methods

```
public class TopClass {
     private static final ComplexObject sdf = initializeComplexObject();
     private static ComplexObject initializeComplexObject(){
                return sdf == null ? new ComplexObject() : sdf;
     }
     public TopClass (
     }
}
```

3) Initialization in constructors ,
4) Static initializer blocks
or what other approach you suggest ...

Does the sdf initializes every time the new TopClass class is creating?
I want sdf field only initialize once in the application lifetime.

Comment: Performance of static initializers almost doesn't matter (especially for such trivial initialization), since it is done just once for a class. The far bigger problem here is making sure that `sdf` is never shared between threads.

Comment: I agree @AndyTurner, aim for readability in this case, not performance. The first one is good, don't add an useless static method if you can do it in one line.

Comment: Also, if this is for logging, most logging frameworks can probably already format the dates you give them (in a configurable manner)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Performance of static initializers almost doesn't matter (especially for such trivial initialization), since it is done just once for a class.

2) This specific method approach is redundant, because it is invoked immediately when the class is initialized; `sdf` is *always* null when the static initializer invokes that method, and you don't invoke that method again (at least, not for the purposes of giving `sdf` a different value). It's also pretty ropy because you are intentionally reading an uninitialized final field.

So, just remove the conditional, and you end up back with effectively the inline initializer approach, with the indirection of a method invocation.

The method approach would be useful if, say, you wanted to do other configuration on the formatter, for instance setting a time zone.

3) Don't initialize static members in a constructor. Constructors are for initializing instance members.

In particular, this requires you to make the static field non-final. This means that you then have to worry about visibility of updates to the field, in order to avoid multiple threads initializing the field because they see a null value

4) Initializing a field at its declaration is simply a shorthand for declaring a static initializer. The first code block in the question is semantically identical to this:

```
private static final ComplexObject sdf;

static {
  sdf = new ComplexObject(); 
}
```

There is no advantage in doing this explicitly, if you can get away with not.

Static initializers are sort-of like anonymous methods. Google's internal Java practices recommend using methods instead of explicit static initializer blocks where possible, in part because you can explicitly invoke them for tests, but also because they necessarily force you to initialize just one field. (I largely agree this is good advice, but note that you lose definite assignment checking in methods - as demonstrated above - which can help to catch certain types of bug).

In conclusion: use `private static final ComplexObject sdf = new ComplexObject();`, because you don't need anything more complicated.

---

The far bigger problem here is correctness, namely ensuring that `sdf` is not shared between threads: before you edited the question, `sdf` was a `SimpleDateFormat`, which is not thread-safe. I have no idea what `ComplexObject` is, but you need to ensure either that it is thread-safe, or that it is accessed in a thread-safe way. Worry about things like that before micro-optimizations.

Comment: The class type of the constant field was not my concern, I just wanted to get the right approach for initializing the constant fields of complex object type. and its initialization when new objects of `LogInfo` is creating.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer says: performance is **absolutely** not an issue here. When starting the JVM, it has to load probably thousands if not hundreds of thousands of classes. How a single constant is intialized during that process doesn't matter at all. Best, we talk nanoseconds for different approaches.

So the only thing that is left to guide a decision: the ideas of clean coding, as in: what is the "most" human readable/understandable way to look at this.

I think: if possible you decide for option 1. If the expression isn't too complicated, and one can simply look at it and understand `SOME_CONSTANT = some expression`, why add complexity of a method call/initializer block to well, complicate things?

But of course: when the expression is already "complicated", and you feel tempted to write a comment to explain *why* it is doing things in a specific way, then a helper method is a good idea. Alone a useful method name might explain what needs to be explained (saving you the need for a comment!)

In other words: always focus on writing the smallest amount of code, that is also easy to read and understand. You don't use an initializer method because you can, but because doing so makes things easier to understand (which in your case: it doesn't). Initializer blocks are (imho) worse, simply because they are so rare. In my eyes, they are an abnormality by know, as you can even create Maps, Lists, ... as "literals" these days.

Comment: I would claim that the only place initializers are actually required is if you are initializing co-dependent fields.

Answer (score 0):

@Andy Turner's answer pretty much answers this question, but I want to add an additional design consideration, since your example object is `ComplexObject` and you seem to focus on the performance aspect.

If you only want to instantiate the object once, but that initialization is quite expensive (`ComplexObject` could suggest such a thing), you might want to initialize the object only once it is actually used, i.e. the first time it is accessed ([lazy initialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization) and [lazy loading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading)).

In its simplext form, you basically hide your `ComplexObject` behind the static getter `private static ComplexObject getComplexObject()`. Then you can use certain idioms:

- [Singleton with double checked locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking#Usage_in_Java)
- [Initialization on demand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom)

If you don't want the additional method, you could define a `Lazy` class, e.g.:

```
class Lazy<T> implements Supplier<T> {

    private T value;
    private final Supplier<T> initializer;

    public Lazy(final Supplier<T> initializer) {
        this.initializer = initializer;
    }

    @Override
    public T get() {
        if (value == null) {
            synchronized (this) {
                if (value == null) {
                    value = initializer.get();
                }
            }
        }
        return value;
    }
}

public class TopClass {
    private static final Lazy<ComplexObject> sdf = new Lazy<>(ComplexObject::new);

    public void exampleMethod() {
        ComplexObject o = sdf.get();
    }
}
```

If you don't want the additional method call of `get()`, you could use the [proxy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern#Virtual_proxy), if you can encapsulate the behavior of `ComplexObject` in an interface. The proxy should then [delegate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern) all method calls of `ComplexObject` to the real instance (In this case, I used the previous code to create the instance by extending `Lazy` which uses access via `get()`, but you can implement the lazy init any way you want in your proxy).

```
interface ComplexObject {}

class ComplexObjectImpl implements ComplexObject {}

class ComplexObjectProxy extends Lazy<ComplexObjectImpl> implements ComplexObject {

    public ComplexObjectProxy() {
        super(ComplexObjectImpl::new);
    }
}

public class TopClass {
    private static final ComplexObject sdf = new ComplexObjectProxy();
}
```